# XmlPullV1.xmlpullparserexception unexpected type(position End_documentid=null)

Tags: android, web-services, xml-parsing

I m going to call add webservice from android after that I got this error..

```
XmlPullv1.xmlpullparserexception unexpected type(position END_Document null@1.0 java.IoInputStreamReader @44e98348 )
```